# Save values from column to an array and loop through

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables: CustomerOrder and OrderItem.

**`CustomerOrder`** has these columns: `ID, CustomerId, DateOrdered, IsCreditCardPayment`.
**`OrderItem`** has these columns: `OrderId(FK from CustomerOrder), ProductId, Quantity, Price`.

What I need to do is calculate the amount of the provision the bank takes from my business when my customers pay with a credit card. The provision is 2%.

My question is how to save the ID's in an array of those orders paid by a credit card and then tell SQL Server to only multiply the quantity and price of the order items that have that same ID from the array?

So far I have this blob:

```
SELECT ID FROM CustomerOrder 
WHERE DateOrdered BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-02-01' 
IF( ? )
    BEGIN
    SELECT ID FROM CustomerOrder
    WHERE IsCreditCardPayment = 1
    END
FROM CustomerOrder
```

I am using:

> Sql Server 14.0.17230.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to save these IDs. Just update them directly:

```
UPDATE CustomerOrder SET
    ProvisionAmount = 0.02 * OrderAmount
WHERE DateOrdered BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-02-01' and IsCreditCardPayment = 1
```

You may also want to tack which orders are already updated, e.g. by adding `ProvosionAmount is null` or add some flag.

If you really need to "save" these IDs, you can use a sub-query:

```
UPDATE AnotherTable SET SomeField = ... where OrderId in (SELECT ID FROM 
    CustomerOrder 
    WHERE DateOrdered BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-02-01' )
```

Or save them to a temp table or table variable:

```
-- Use table variable
DECLARE @OrderIDs table(OrderId int)
insert into @OrderIDs
SELECT ID FROM 
CustomerOrder 
WHERE DateOrdered BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-02-01'

-- Create a new temp table
SELECT ID FROM 
insert into #OrderIDs
CustomerOrder 
WHERE DateOrdered BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-02-01'

-- Insert into pre-created table
CREATE TABLE #OrderIDs(OrderId int)
insert into #OrderIDs
SELECT ID FROM 
CustomerOrder 
WHERE DateOrdered BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2000-02-01'
```

and then use one of the above to update your data.

Comment: Hey Andrey thank you for taking the time to answer my question. I read somewhere that data that could be calculated isn't supposed to be put in a table because it was considered a waste of disk space and rather be calculated "on the fly". However the solution you offered seems pretty simple and awesome, therefore I'm accepting it.